# Making a Child window move with Parent in a frameless Electron window

Tags: javascript, html, css, client, electron

I'm currently working on a frameless application with ElectronJS where I'm trying to have a parent window handle the dragging, minimize, maximize, and exit, as well as a controller for the child window which will handle all of the content. However, when I set the parent to the main window in my main.js, the content window stays in place when I move the parent.

Below is my main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;
let contentWindow;

app.on('ready', function createWindow(){
    //Create window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        frame: false
    })
    contentWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        frame: false,
        parent: mainWindow
    })

    //load html for window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/html/mainWindow.html'),
        protocol:'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    contentWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/html/contentWindow.html'),
        protocol:'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```

One of the div's in my mainWindow.html has `-webkit-app-region: drag;` to allow it to act as the top bar like a normal window. Basically I would like this to move both windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's like what [@Dennis L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9046585/dennis-l) said, use the `move` event provided in the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-move). I though it only support mac, but i'm using windows. And once i tried it working.

In my case, i'm using `getPosition` method to keep track of the `mainWindow` position during move or drag. And then `setPosition` of the `secondWindow` with value that came from `mainWindow` itself.

```
  mainWindow.on('move', function() {
    let position = mainWindow.getPosition();
    secondWindow.setPosition(position[0], position[1]);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know that your goal is basically that, what only is supported under macOS with parent and child window [Doc](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), the way i reach that my child moves with the parent, is that i listen on the move event from the parent and recalculate the position for the child. Not the best way but it works.

```
mainWindow.on("move", function () {"calculate and set new position here"}
```